# Files are saved locally and not to the document library

Tags: 2013, document-library, client

I'm using SharePoint Foundation 2013.

I'm facing this issue: A user is browsing a document library and want to open a Word document to modify it. SharePoint doesn't open Word automatically, but it starts the file download.

Obviously the file is saved locally and modifications are applied only to the local file and not saved to the document library file.

Any suggestion to solve this problem?

Comment: What browser is used, what Office version is used, is the site in Trusted sites zone in Internet Explorer?

Answer (score -1):

You need to set "Browser File Handling" to Permissive in Central Admin for a specific web application.

Go to CA
Select Web Application
Click General Settings button in Ribbon
From menu select General Settings again
You will see a "Browser File Handling" setting on Web Application General Settings page
Set it to Permissive
Close browser and do iisreset

Comment: This is certainly not true for Word documents and opening them in the client application instead of dowloading